# Why when clicking on numpad_0 or only 0 i don't see anything with the camera?

Tags: modeling, camera

The camera is viewing the city.
I scaled the camera made it bigger.

[image: Camera view city]

Then i click on numpad_0 and see

[image: Camera after clicked on numpad_0(INS)]

But if i will make a new project with only the cube in the start and will click the numpad_0 it will lock and show the cube.

Why it's not showing the city ?

Comment: Scaling the camera object has no effect whatsoever, other than its visible size in the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to your far clip setting under: Camera Tab -> Lens -> Clipping -> Far.

Adjust that to a ludicrous number and you should see your buildings, but I'd suggest adjusting your scenes scale since this gigantic scale may cause other problems down the lane.